# What did Mercy do to Reaper?

Tags: overwatch

While playing the game I heard a few dialogues between Reaper and Mercy

Mercy: "This is not what I intended for you, Reyes."

Reaper: "You knew exactly what you were doing."

Mercy: "What happened to you?!"

Reaper: "You tell me, Doc."

I'm intrigued, what did Mercy do that gave Reaper so much hate

Comment: Gabriel Reyes was presumably killed in the blast at Overwatch HQ, and it's currently unknown how he has returned. However, these lines do lead to some speculation that Dr. Ziegler either caused his current wraith-like condition, or at least, that Reaper believes she did

Comment: And considering her confirmed work with Genji and presumed work with 76, this seems possible

Comment: There was some lore floating around that she tried to revive him, but failed to do it properly. As a result, his cells destroy and recreate themselves at an astonishing rate, which allows his use of teleportation.

Comment: I just thought this meant that even Reaper doesn't know what was done to him. Mercy doesn't know, that's why she's asking, but it's like you go to a doctor about a rash and the doctor goes "what's wrong with your skin?!" You sort of expect the doctor to know more about such things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's hinted at (if not outright confirmed) in Overwatch lore that Mercy was the one who was responsible for Reaper's current condition after he was apparently killed at Overwatch HQ. Her attempts to revive him didn't go as planned, and rather than being restored as the Gabriel Reyes everyone knew, his cells started to destroy and regenerate themselves in a very rapid manner, which is what causes him to sometimes appear as a black fog. This is what allows him to assume his "wraith" form and allows him to teleport.

Comment: If you add a source, I believe this answer would be upvoted much

Comment: But wiki says that Mercy have no actual "revive from dead" ability in lore, that is only useful in-game mechanics.

Comment: @Exerion Your right, but Revival is also used in real life when people are recently "dead". Some surgeries require you to effectively kill the patient, and then revive them later. Without external help, they are dead and will stay dead, but the right medical treatment can get them going again. That is what it sounds like happened to Reaper. No doctor can revive a Skeleton, but a man dead for a few hours, its happened before.    If we can fix the damage that killed them before unfix-able damage happens, they can come back. Near perfect Cryogenic freezing can extend that time near indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

It was [Moira O'Deorain](https://overwatch.blizzard.com/en-us/heroes/moira/) who experimented on Reyes during her time in Blackwatch, Overwatch's covert ops division and again later after she joined Talon.

The first dialog in this question has never actually existed in the game and was recently featured in a Mandela Effect in video games video.

Note: I realize this question is old, but since this question appears in searches for this subject, I figure I should set the record straight.

Comment: good answer for an update to lore. may be worth linking some backing evidence for the 2nd paragraph. I believe there was a tweet by someone involved in the development for overwatch stating that voice line never existed

Comment: @Dragonrage Unfortunately, Michael Chu's twitter post linked to BattleNet's old forums, which are apparently long gone.  Attempting to pull up the correct page on the archive.org Wayback machine pops up XML errors.

Comment: If you want to try for yourself, the URL is https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20747844983#post-16